# how to remove sticky (permanent) notifications from notification bar?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications, notification-bar, sony-xperia-s

I have a buggy app installed in my phone, which sometimes creates permanent download progress notification with animated icon but **fails to remove it from notification bar** by its own.

I tried to remove the notification manually (swipe it off) but it is sticky and can't be removed. I tried "clear" option in notification bar, but again no success and it is still there! I even stopped that app which created the notification, but no change.

The only option that I have to remove such sticky and buggy notifications is to restart the device, which is very unpleasant.

**Which app, hack, command, gesture, etc... I can use to remove that sticky notification?**

*My device is **`Sony Xperia S`** running **`ICS 4.0.4 stock ROM`** *(rooted)*

Comment: This may not directly answer your question but you could use a status bar replacement like Omega Statusbar (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1825283)

Comment: Contact the app developer.  If they don't reply, leave a review on the Google Play store.  If they still don't respond, replace the buggy app or upgrade to a newer Android version.  Some non-stock ROM may be available for your device, such as CyanogenMod, which is based on a newer Android version.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Jelly Bean, then in manage apps, you can turn off notifications for the specific app. Keep in mind, this will turn off all notifications for the app.

[image]

Comment: Nice hint, but I don't have that "show notifications" checkbox in my device. Maybe your screenshot is from Jelly Bean?! BTW, I want all notifications from that buggy app to be shown, but also be removable by myself.

Comment: oh, maybe that is a Jelly Bean feature. sorry.

Comment: Turning off and back on will do the trick. No need to turn the notifications off permanently.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem... You should go to settings, apps, all, find there download manager and clear all data there. It helps in my case. Good luck :-)

Comment: Note that the "Clear data" button performs an irreversible action.  Once you clear the data, there is no way to get it back.  In the case of a download manager, though, it's probably fine; the data is probably unimportant.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't remove any buggy notification from notification bar, then do this

Goto **Settings**-->**Applications**-->(click on **App** which created that notification)-->**force close**.

then ***Reopen*** that Application.

Answer (score 2):

Go to;

- Setting-> Apps -> All Apps -> Download Manager
- Select download manager
- Clear Cache and data.

Notification of sticky downloads will be removed.  I've tested this on a Sony Xperia J with Android version 4.0

Comment: Note that the "Clear data" button performs an irreversible action.  Once you clear the data, there is no way to get it back.  In the case of a download manager, though, it's probably fine; the data is probably unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

Are you by chance addressing Bazaar?
If that's the case you can simply go the application specific page and hit the cancel button. This should remove the notification.

Comment: Yes, exactly! But I can't hit cancel because the app download completed and installed, but notification remained on 17% and didn't vanish. Finally, I removed it by starting download for another app from Bazaar! BTW, I would like to know a more general solution for such buggy apps.

Comment: I don't think there is anything we can do except notify the app makers to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered by nikola, you should go to `Settings->Apps->All`. Select the Download Manager in the app list, and then press <kbd>Clear all data</kbd>.

You may have to restart the mobile after this is done.

Comment: Note that the "Clear data" button performs an irreversible action.  Once you clear the data, there is no way to get it back.  In the case of a download manager, though, it's probably fine; the data is probably unimportant.